# NopCommerce add extra or custom tab menu in admin area using a plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, nopcommerce

I am new in `NopCommerce` developing a small plugin for personal use. My problem is I am trying to add a extra tab menu item in the menu bar in Admin panel. I have gone through the [documentation](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/How+to+add+a+menu+item+into+the+administration+area+from+a+plugin) of doing this types of work. But I am totally confused what they are saying, where I have to add those provided code.

According to the official documentation I am failed to understand because I don't have or used the `Plugin.cs` file where I have to implement interface `IAdminMenuPlugin`. So Where can I implement these method. My major problem is I don't know what is the work of plugin.cs file. Because I didn't find any such class in existing `plugin` which are provided in `NopCommerce` framework. I am using `3.80` version of it.

Comment: So did I. I didn't found such class. Will you visit the documentation link. so that you get confused like me.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin.cs you are looking for, is the file containing the class that implements `Nop.Core.Plugins.IPlugin` interface, that class is the one where implement `IAdminMenuPlugin`.

All the official plugins implement `IPlugin` inheriting from `Nop.Core.Plugins.BasePlugin` class, for example, `NivoSliderPlugin.cs` declares `NivoSliderPlugin` class and inherits from `BasePlugin`.

NopCommerce will autodiscover all this plugins (the `IPlugin` interface implementation) and load them into the system and if this class implements `IAdminMenuPlugin` the `ManageSiteMap` method will be called

So you will need something like this:

```
 public class CustomPlugin : BasePlugin, IAdminMenuPlugin
 {

      ...

        public void ManageSiteMap(SiteMapNode rootNode)
        {
           // here you can manage the menu from rootNode
        }

     ...
}
```